# Phonegap prevent pageinit

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Iam not quite sure if I use pageinit event correct. Iam working with only 1 data-role="page".
Each '.html file' is a data-role="content" which is wether shown or hidden via javascript.

```
    $(document).delegate("#index", "pageinit", function(event, ui) {
  cookie = null;
  isLoggedIn(); //cookie = true || false
  initRotation();
  initNavigation();
  initService();
  .....
  if (cookie == null) {
    $('#login').show();
    $('#home, #foot, #service').hide();
  } else {
    $('#login, #service').hide();
    $('#foot, #home').show();
    $('#naviHome').addClass("ui-btn-active"); // ui-state-persist?!
  }
});
```

It worked fine so far but now Iam trying to let the user take a picture for a form. When the camera is opened and the user 'saves' that picture, Android onRestart() event is fired which fires pageinit() event again.
My two questions are: Is my idea of show/hide divs all the time with good performance and can you prevent pageinit call?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable that keeps track of where pageinit should or shouldnt be fired. and when the user opens the camera the variable can be changed so that when it the picture gets saved and it tries to fire pageinit it doesnt. and then switch the variable back so it can fire again for other events.

Also regarding showing and hidding divs, this isnt best for performance but its better than constantly loading up pages. You may want to look into a framework that loads up all your templates(html) and loads/swaps info and templates with js. Like backbone.js